Saving Filtered List to .CSV file in Python
I have a CSV file containing measurements of sample objects. I've been able to filter the list using Pandas and the Python statistics module. I'm trying to then exclude objects that are either less than 2 standard deviations or greater than 2 standard deviations from the mean and then save the final list to a new csv file. Printouts to the shell confirm the filtering and statistical calculations are working as expected. However, the new CSV file still contains all of the original objects.
I've tried researching the issue but haven't identified what error I'm making or how to fix it. Would appreciate any assistance.
The following is my code:

import statistics
import pandas as pd
import csv

data = pd.read_csv('/Users/myname/Documents/Data/MyData.csv')

count_row = data.shape[0]  # Gives number of rows (items)
print ("N =", count_row)

mean = data["Area"].mean().round(2)
print ("Average = ", mean)

sd = data["Area"].std().round(2)
print("SD =", sd)

Lower2SD = mean - (2*sd)
print ("Mean - 2SD =","%.2f" % Lower2SD)

Upper2SD = mean + (2*sd)

print ("Mean + 2SD =","%.2f" % Upper2SD)

print ("Mean +- 2SD = ","%.2f" %Lower2SD, "to", "%.2f" % Upper2SD)

new =list(filter(lambda x: x<Lower2SD, data["Area"]))
print()
print("Value(s) of specimens below the Mean -2SD: ")
print(new)

new =list(filter(lambda x: x>Upper2SD, data["Area"]))
print()
print("Value(s) of specimens exceeding the Mean +2SD: ")
print(new)

adjusted=list(filter(lambda x: x>Lower2SD or x<Upper2SD, data["Area"]))
print()
print("Value(s) of specimens within 2SD: ")
print(adjusted)

global header
header = ["Area"]

with open('/Users/myname/Documents/Data/AdjustedData.csv', 'a', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)

    for i in adjusted:
        writer.writerow([i])




Why are you not just using df.to_csv ?

Note that images are not useful for data.  Paste a sample of the actual text of the input CSV that illustrates the problem when run with your code, which should be a [mcve].

you shouldn't be using the statistics module, and you shouldn't be using filter. you should be using numpy/pandas methods

x>Lower2SD or x<Upper2SD

This condition is the problem.  It does not exclude any values at all.
If x is a very low score, x<Upper2SD will be true, so it will be included in the filtered list.
If x is a very high score, x>Lower2SD will be true, so it will be included in the filtered list.
I think you want an and condition here, not or.
Python even has a special syntax for this kind of comparison:
Lower2SD < x < Upper2SD


import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('/Users/myname/Documents/Data/MyData.csv')

mean = data["Area"].mean()
sd = data["Area"].std()
upper = mean + 2 * sd
lower = mean - 2 * sd

adjusted = data.loc[(data["Area"] < upper) & (data["Area"] > lower)]

adjusted.to_csv('/Users/myname/Documents/Data/AdjustedData.csv', index=False)


Thank you! I confirmed that the data exported correctly plus your approach kept all of the other data elements intact. I had tried df.to.csv approach but made a typo and put cvs instead....My bad.
